# Get order of letters in a string python

Tags: python, string, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to get the order number of characters in a string. It should also take into consideration when the letter first occurs as the first order For example:

```
 'abc' 
  = 1,2,3

 'dfe'
  = 1,3,2

  'xef'
  = 3,1,2

  'aba'
  = 1,3,2

  'bba'
  =2,3,1
```

Is there a easy way to do so?

Comment: What do you want to happen in the case of repeated characters?

Comment: Ive edited my post with an example. so the first occurrence of the letter should be ordered first .

Comment: bbac would be 2,3,1,4

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
def ranker(s):
    ranked = sorted(range(len(s)),key=lambda x: (s[x], x))
    d = dict(zip(ranked, range(len(ranked))))
    return [d[i]+1 for i in range(len(s))]
```

which gives me

```
>>> ranker("abc")
[1, 2, 3]
>>> ranker("dfe")
[1, 3, 2]
>>> ranker("xef")
[3, 1, 2]
>>> ranker("aba")
[1, 3, 2]
>>> ranker("bba")
[2, 3, 1]
>>> ranker("bbac")
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much and thank you everyone else

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to @CoryKramer's answer. Instead of using the `index` method on tuples, it uses a dictionary lookup, which might be faster for long strings.

```
def order(s):
    ordered = sorted(s)
    position = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(ordered)}
    return [position[c]+1 for c in s]

>>> order('abc')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> order('dfe')
[1, 3, 2]
>>> order('xef')
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to edit this so it works with duplicates? Example:   'bba' =2,3,1

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from collections import defaultdict, deque

s = "aabca"
ranks = defaultdict(deque)
groups, cn = (v for k, v in groupby(sorted(s))), count(1)

for v in groups:
    for ch in v:
        ranks[ch].append(str(next(cn)))

print(",".join(ranks[ch].popleft() for ch in s))
2,3,1,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, try it

```
s = 'badca'
order = []

for x in range(len(s)):
    order.append(0)
print(order)

for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if i == j:
            order[i] = order[i] + 1
        elif i != j:
            if s[i] > s[j]:
                order[i] = order[i] + 1
            elif (s[i] == s[j]) and (j > i):
                order[j] = order[j] + 1



print(order)
```